# Single TypeSafe Console for 2 different machines which are running its own actor system

Tags: console, akka, typesafe

We have same Akka application deployed on multiple machines. How do we configure typesafe console to get statistics from all machines and displayed on single console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to start a atmos collector on each of the machines, configure it with the same database. Then on one system run the atmos analyze, atmos query and console processes, all configured with the same database as before.

As far as I know, you can do this only with a license, the free developer version only allows in-memory storage, therefore you cannot run the atmos modules separately. The licensed version also comes with an expanded documentation, where an example with collecting data from multiple modes is described.